# How to check if it's a tie in "Tic-Tac-Toe"?

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I was following a tutorial and changed the winner check code and it works fine (it was all if statements in the tutorial) but couldn't figure out how to check if it's a tie. I tried a for loop which would increase a count variable according to how many places in the grid is filled but it didnt work well. Also in some games the person gets 2 rounds. e.g. X plays but it doesnt switch to O. Im new to java, we learned python last semester so im sorry if this is a dumb question. (https://codeshare.io/eV4Bwx this is the tutors code to check the winner)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class TicTacToe implements ActionListener{

    Random random = new Random();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel title_panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel button_panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel textfield = new JLabel();
    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[9];
    boolean player1_turn;



    TicTacToe(){

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800,800);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(50,50,50));
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);

        textfield.setBackground(new Color(25, 25, 25));
        textfield.setForeground(new Color(40,23,50));
        textfield.setFont(new Font("Ink Free", Font.BOLD,75));
        textfield.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        textfield.setText("Tic-Tac-Toe");
        textfield.setOpaque(true);

        title_panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        title_panel.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 100);

        button_panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        textfield.setBackground(new Color(50, 100, 150));

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            buttons[i] = new JButton();
            button_panel.add(buttons[i]);
            buttons[i].setFont(new Font("MV Boli", Font.BOLD,120));
            buttons[i].setFocusable(false);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
        }

        title_panel.add(textfield);
        frame.add(title_panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(button_panel);


        firstTurn();

        check_x();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            if (e.getSource() == buttons[i]){
                if (player1_turn){
                    if (buttons[i].getText() == ""){
                        buttons[i].setForeground(new Color(25,50,55));
                        buttons[i].setText("X");
                        player1_turn = false;
                        textfield.setText("O turn");
                    }
                }else {
                    if (buttons[i].getText() == ""){
                        buttons[i].setForeground(new Color(55,0,25));
                        buttons[i].setText("O");
                        player1_turn = true;
                        textfield.setText("X turn");
                }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void firstTurn(){

        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (random.nextInt(2) == 0){
            player1_turn = true;
            textfield.setText("X turn");
        }else{
            player1_turn = false;
            textfield.setText("O turn");
        }

    }

    public void check_x(){

        int[][] win = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}};

        while (true) {

            //Check Y
            boolean t = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < win.length; i++) {

                int q = win[i][0];
                int w = win[i][1];
                int e = win[i][2];

                if ((buttons[q].getText() == "O") && (buttons[w].getText() == "O") && (buttons[e].getText() == "O")) {
                    textfield.setText("O wins");

                    t = true;

                    buttons[q].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    buttons[w].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    buttons[e].setBackground(Color.GREEN);

                    for(int s=0;s<9;s++) {
                        buttons[s].setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }

            }if(t){break;}

            //Check X
            boolean n = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < win.length; i++) {

                int w = win[i][1];
                int q = win[i][0];
                int e = win[i][2];

                if ((buttons[q].getText() == "X") && (buttons[w].getText() == "X") && (buttons[e].getText() == "X")) {
                    textfield.setText("X wins");

                    n = true;

                    buttons[q].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    buttons[w].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    buttons[e].setBackground(Color.GREEN);

                    for(int s=0;s<9;s++) {
                        buttons[s].setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }if (n){break;}





}
    }
}
```

Comment: `buttons[i].getText() == ""` is not how you compare Strings in Java

Comment: @scary-wombat i figured, ide gave a warning too but thats how it was done in the video so i didnt wanna mess with cause it worked. How should i change it ?

Comment: use `buttons[i].getText().equals("")`

Comment: Unrelated: learn about java naming conventions. In java we use camelCase for variables and method names. "_" is only for SOME_CONSTANT. Also: only make those variables fields that are needed in more than one method. After creation, none of your methods uses the two panel fields. So there is no need to make them members of your class. Create them, add them, forget about them.

Answer (score 0):

For good practice, the only thing between your loops different is the X and the O.
You could put it in a separate function and call it twice: didWin("X"); didWin("O");

> I tried a for loop which would increase a count variable according to how many places in the grid is filled but it didnt work well.

That would exactly be what i do. What did not work?

```
        private int[][] win = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}}; // either can be init like that or filled in constructor

 public void check_x(){


        while (true) {
if(didWin("X") || didWin("O") || isDraw()) break;
}
}

private boolean didWin(string playerToken){
            for (int i = 0; i < win.length; i++) {

                int q = win[i][0];
                int w = win[i][1];
                int e = win[i][2];

                if ((buttons[q].getText().equals(playerToken)) && (buttons[w].getText().equals(playerToken)) && (buttons[e].getText().equals(playerToken))) {

                    endGame(playerToken+" wins"); // more useful to end the game with a separate function, so we can use it for the draw again.
return true;
                }

            }
return false;
}
private void endGame(string message){
                    textfield.setText(message);

                    buttons[q].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    buttons[w].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    buttons[e].setBackground(Color.GREEN);

                    for(int s=0;s<9;s++) {
                        buttons[s].setEnabled(false);
                    }
}
private boolean isDraw(){
 int usedFields = 0;
 for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
   if(buttons[i].getText().equals("")) usedFields++;
 }
  if( usedFields==9){
   endGame("its a draw");
return true;
  }
return false;
}
```

If you want, put the whole while(true) away, rename it to checkGameEnd() and call it each time in actionPerformed.

Add another variable player1_symbol and you can change between X and O for player 1 and play more rounds.